# Categories url in not visible when calling inside page template

Tags: category, url

Categories url in not visible when calling inside page template. But this works in catalog template. How to make this accessible in a phtml block of page template?

```
<?php
foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category):
     echo $this->drawItem($_category); // this gives the category name but not the url
endforeach 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this;

```
<?php   
$root = Mage::app() -> getStore() -> getRootCategoryId();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category') 
           -> getCollection() 
           -> addAttributeToSelect('*') 
           -> addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', array('eq' => $root));

foreach ($collection as $_category){
      echo $_category -> getUrl();
}
```